# Django request.method is "{}GET" when request from axios after built with vue-cli

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, axios, vue-cli

I'm using axios with Vue in my project. While under development (npm run serve), it's worked correctly. But after built, any request after 'PUT' request will have "{}" in front of http method, such as "{}GET", "{}PUT".

as I've tested, I've got this
[state diagram](https://i.screenshot.net/x1ezvh9).

```
// CASE 1 : OK
axios.put('someurl')  // HTTP_METHOD is 'PUT'
axios.get('someurl')  // HTTP_METHOD is 'PUT'

// CASE 2 : HAS CURLY BRACKET IN METHOD
axios.put('someurl', {})  // HTTP_METHOD is 'PUT'
axios.put('someurl', {})  // HTTP_METHOD is '{}PUT'
axios.post('someurl', {})  // HTTP_METHOD is '{}POST'
axios.delete('someurl', {})  // HTTP_METHOD is '{}DELETE' 
axios.get('someurl', {})  // HTTP_METHOD is 'GET'
```

this is some logs from django

```
[28/May/2019 20:45:15] "GET /api/colla/comments/177/notify/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4
[28/May/2019 20:45:16] "PUT /api/colla/comments/177/notify/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5
[28/May/2019 20:45:19] "{}POST /api/colla/comments/177/notify/ HTTP/1.1" 405 43
[28/May/2019 20:45:25] "{}POST /api/colla/comments/177/notify/ HTTP/1.1" 405 43
[28/May/2019 20:45:30] "{}PUT /api/colla/comments/177/notify/ HTTP/1.1" 405 42
[28/May/2019 20:45:36] "{}DELETE /api/colla/comments/177/notify/ HTTP/1.1" 405 45
[28/May/2019 20:45:39] "DELETE /api/colla/comments/177/notify/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4
```

Comment: can you post a sample request? your post data is probably always empty

Comment: I want to send empty request, and after I've tested it again, I see that it will only be occured when I put an empty object in the 2nd arguments of axios request. may be it's a bug of library.

Comment: At last, I just prevent my code from calling axios with an empty object to make it work. Thanks anyway.